# Наибольшая общая подпоследовательность Python Помогите ускорить

Tags: python, python-3.x

Помогите пожалуйста ускорить код на `python`! надо чтобы при входных данных длиной до 10000 символов программа работала меньше чем за 2 секунды.

```py
a = input()
b = input()

n = len(a)
m = len(b)


dm = [0 for i in range(m + 1)]
d, di, dj, dij = 0, 0, 0, 0

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    dn = [0]
    for j in range(1, m + 1):
        di, dj, dij = dm[j], d, dm[j - 1] + 1
        d = di if di > dj else dj
        if a[i - 1] == b[j - 1]:
            d = dij if d < dij else d
        dn.append(d)

    d = 0
    dm = dn

print(dm[-1])
```

я сделал маленькую оптимизацию для памяти, чтобы хранилась только последние две строки матрицы и предыдущий ее элемент

Comment: Без детального чтения кода: 1) Это какое-то вычисление матриц? 2) Мультипроцессинг не пробовали использовать, если большой объем вычислений? 3) А зачем оптимизация памяти? Тут же, скорее, загрузка процессора будут важна, если это вычислительные операции - тогда любые действия по оптимизации памяти только увеличат время. 4) На какой машине 2с надо? Будет не везде одинаково.

Comment: @Сергей это для решения задачи, там ограничения по времени 2 секунды, а по памяти 64 мегабайта, и вот если не использовать оптимизацию памяти, тогда выход за ограничения по памяти, и если с оптимизацией по памяти, то уже через несколько тестов выход за пределы по времени

Comment: @Сергей это задача Наибольшая Общая Подпоследовательность

Comment: Мультипроцессинг не пробовали использовать?

Comment: @Сергей а что это?

Comment: Это то, что сейчас изучаю:-))) https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135326/discussion-between--and-zolars).

Comment: @Сергей к сожалению это не подходит, тк на процессоре там, где задача на тестах проверяется всего одно ядро, и если я правильно понял, эта библиотека сторонняю

Comment: Это часть базового курса Python + это основная документация Python, как я знаю. А мультипроцессинг работает на одном ядре, это не мультипотоковость. + вы читали статьи типа https://habr.com/ru/post/142825/ - и выбрали самый эффективный алгоритм из них?

Comment: а суть задачи в чем?)

Comment: @D.Vinogradov в нахождении наибольшей общей подпоследовательности у двух строк https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3XTTNBLfQ3g

Comment: я так понимаю без использования сторонних библиотек?

Comment: @D.Vinogradov да

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы на plain Python выполнялось миллиард операций в секунду? (10000*10000*20операцийвцикле)